# Is it possible that a Black Hole could be split in half creating two Black Holes?

Tags: science-based

We are all familiar with the origin of most detected gravitational waves being the result of the merger between two distant black holes. While such an event would make for an interesting backdrop I thought of an even better one, but wanted to verify that it is something that could happen.

Imagine that instead of a merger between two Black Holes the smaller Black Hole is being ripped asunder by massive tidal forces from the larger Black Hole. This would eventually rip the Black Hole apart releasing a massive ton of energy, creating two Black Holes that then escape the gravity of the larger Black Hole and if the event could be seen it would look something like cell mitosis.

My question, therefore, is whether such an event could occur. And if so what would happen to the material within the black hole, would some sort of exotic matter be ejected from within the Black Hole that could then eventually wind up on a rocky planet?

Comment: Hi, ThisIsImpossible, welcome to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange! Your questions is very similar to -- and likely a duplicate of -- [this earlier one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/142362/627), which you may find useful.

Comment: @HDE226868 The question you link is "Can a black be split in N parts"  whereas this question is "Can a black hole be split in two parts". I would say this is a duplicate question.

Comment: *"Escape the gravity of the larger Black Hole":* Once an object crosses to inside the event horizon, the direction towards the singularity becomes time-like. The event horizon is in the object's *past*. Escaping does not require "massive forces", it requires time travel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this cannot happen. The most basic description of a black hole is an object so dense that its escape velocity exceeds the speed of light. The distance from the 'hole at which escape velocity *is* the speed of light is the event horizon.

You're proposing to re-shape the event horizon into two separate pieces which then don't re-merge. This seems to require faster-than-light movement.